# 記号を使って ToDo を記述するようなフォーマットを何と呼ぶ？

Tags: file

以前何かの記事で読んだ記憶があるのですが、ToDoやメモなどをわかりやすく記述する書き方？
があるらしく、その書き方を知りたいのですが何という書き方が思い出せずにいます。

確か `*` がところどころ使われていたような気がします。

情報少なくて申し訳ありません。何かピンとくるものがあれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

emacs で使われている、 org-mode である可能性はわりとありえます。

```
* TODO これは todo ヘッダ
** TODO サブタスク
   親タスクは、サブタスクが完了するまで終了にできない設定ができたはず。

** TODO サブタスク2
   チェックリストっぽいこともできます
   * [X] 項目1
   * [-] 項目2
     * [ ] 子1
     * [X] 子2
```

Answer (score 4):

TODO用に限定されたものではありませんが、[Markdown](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) 記法ではないでしょうか。

ルールに従って記述しておくことで、プレーンテキストの状態でもそれなりに見やすいですが、ビューワなどでHTMLに変換することができます (ここスタック・オーバーフローでもMarkdownが使用できます)。

リストの簡単な例は

```
- 順序なしリストのアイテム
- 別のアイテム
```

- 順序なしリストのアイテム
- 別のアイテム

```
1. 順序付きリストのアイテム
2. 別のアイテム
```

1. 順序付きリストのアイテム
2. 別のアイテム

Comment: これに補足すると、GitHub Flavored MarkdownというMarkdown方言では `- [ ]` と記述することでタスクリストを作成できます。 参考：[About task lists - GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-task-lists)

Answer (score 0):

「ChangeLog メモ」かも知れません。

それらしいと思わせる点:

- `*` が多用される
- 日本語圏では活発な発表や意見交換があり、雑誌などの記事もあった

違うかもと思わせる点:

- 露出が多かったのは20年くらい前
- ToDoの管理は主要な目的ではない

#### 記事

『Unix Magazine』:

> Unix Magazine 誌に 2002年1月号から 2003年2月号にかけて連載していた記事の元の原稿です。
> ...
> そこで山下氏は試行錯誤の末に ChangeLog形式でメモを取るのがよろしい、という結論に辿りついた。そんなわけで、私は氏から伝授された ChangeLog形式でメモを取っている。ちなみに、我々の周りでは他に6人ほど ChangeLogメモを実践している人がいるが、 みんな気に入っているようである。
> ...
> この ChangeLogのフォーマットでメモを取ることを、私は ChangeLogメモと呼んでいる。典型的な ChangeLogメモは次のようなものである。
>
> ```
> 2001-10-17  Satoru Takabayashi  <satoru@namazu.org>
>
> 　　　　* Unix: タイムゾーンを一時的に変更する方法: % TZ=GMT date
> 　　　　土 11月  3 13:30:28 GMT 2001
> 　　　　- TZ環境変数を変更すればいい
>
> 　　　　* Ruby: Enumerable#inject の使い方
> 　　　　% irb
> 　　　　>> (1..10).inject(0) {|x, y| x + y}
> 　　　　=> 55
> 　　　　- Haskellの場合:
> 　　　　% hugs
> 　　　　Prelude> foldl (\ x y -> x + y) 0 [1..10] 
> 　　　　55
>
> 　　　　* アイディア: cdbiff: メールの到着を CD-ROMドライブがお知らせ
> 　　　　- ejectコマンド一発。ローテクなところがいい
>
> 2001-10-16  Satoru Takabayashi  <satoru@namazu.org>
>
> 　　　　* Windows: フォーカスのあたっているウィンドウをキャプチャする
> 　　　　- Alt + PrintScreen キー
> ```
>
> —— [横着プログラミング 第1回: Unixのメモ技術](http://0xcc.net/unimag/1/)

『情報処理』:

> ...
> この「自分データベース」活用のポイントはやはり検索です. その点で, 紙媒体よりも電子メモが適しています. 電子メモのツールは多種多様なものがありますが, 私が長年使っているのが, ChangeLog というフォーマットに一切合財記録していくという「ChangeLog メモ」です. 日付＋内容という単純な日誌形式です. 以下に例を挙げます.
>
> ```
> 2003-07-30 YAMASHITA Tatsuo <yto@nais.to>
>
>   * update:「100 円ショップで買って良かったもの」を更新. 二品追加.
>   <http://nais.to/~yto/doc/zb/0014.html>
>
>   * サーバ作業: aaa.conf を変更. 使用スクリプト：~/work/conv/a2a.pl
>
>   * 出張: 神保町. 往復 1100 円. 帰社後出張申請.
>   報告書作成 C:/doc/030730-rep.do
> ```
>
> ...
>
> —— [私の情報整理術:ChangeLogメモによる自分データベースの構築](http://id.nii.ac.jp/1001/00065607/)